# Catch part of Try-Catch not executing

Tags: java, exception, try-catch

I am writing a shortcode for learning purpose that asks the user to enter a password to login to Facebook. I am testing exception handling, and for some reason, the *Catch* part is not executing when the password is wrong. The code is:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class FacebookLogin {
    
    
    public static void printPassword() {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String password;
        
        try {
            
            System.out.print("Enter your password : ");
            password = sc.next();
        
        } catch (Exception x) {
            do {            
            System.out.println("Your password is incorrect. Try again!");
            System.out.print("Enter your password : ");
            sc.nextLine();
            password = sc.next();
            
            
            } while (password != "password");
        }
        sc.close();
        
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        
        System.out.println("Welcome to Facebook!");
        
        printPassword();
        
        System.out.println("Congratulations, you have logged in to Facebook!");
        
        
    }
    
}
```

Few runs of the above script:

> Welcome to Facebook!
>
> Enter your password : ksskasjaks
>
> Congratulations, you have logged in to Facebook!

Another run:

> Welcome to Facebook!
>
> Enter your password : password
>
> Congratulations, you have logged in to Facebook!

I excepted something like this, of course the only password here is "password":

> Welcome to Facebook!
>
> Enter your password : ksskasjaks
>
> Your password is incorrect. Try again!
>
> Enter your password : password
>
> Congratulations, you have logged in to Facebook!

Any clue why it is not working as intended? Thanks.

Comment: Where do you check the password? The code makes no sense. The `catch` block will only be executed when there is some exception.

Comment: Actually `Scanner::next` can throw unchecked Exception when there is no token or scanner is closed but I guess none of those cases apply here so the catch block is not executed :)

Comment: I thought the while (password != "password"); can check the right password which is just "password" . @Michael

Comment: but that `while` loop is inside the `Exception` block which will only be executed when an `Exception` is thrown inside the `try` block (and BTW Exception should be an exception and not used for *normal* flow)

Comment: @user102859 don't use `!=` (or `==`) to compare strings. Use `.equals`.

Comment: Try changing `while (password != "password");` to `while(!"password".equals(password))` as you want to check if the string contents are the same, not if they're the two same instances.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With try catch:

```
 public static void enterPassword() throws Exception {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    String password;
    System.out.print("Enter your password : ");
    password = sc.next();
    if (!password.equals("password")) {
        throw new Exception();
    }
}

public static void printPassword() {
    try {
        enterPassword();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Your password is incorrect. Try again!");
        printPassword();
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {


    System.out.println("Welcome to Facebook!");

    printPassword();

    System.out.println("Congratulations, you have logged in to Facebook!");


}
```

Comment: Thanks Willen. Your solution is great. I was confused with exception handling. But learnt a lot from your answer. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

No need for try catch, i guess this is what you wanted:

```
public static void printPassword() {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    String password;

    System.out.print("Enter your password : ");
    sc.nextLine();
    password = sc.next();
    while (!password.equals("password")) {
        System.out.println("Your password is incorrect. Try again!");
        System.out.print("Enter your password : ");
        sc.nextLine();
        password = sc.next();
    }

    sc.close();

}

public static void main(String[] args) {


    System.out.println("Welcome to Facebook!");

    printPassword();

    System.out.println("Congratulations, you have logged in to Facebook!");


}
```

Comment: Thanks for this. While I would do this in a different way, I want to solve it with try/catch, not any other method. It's a way to learn exception handling.